# How can I access to an HTML control runat server from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="JOB_CODE" 
<EditItemTemplate> 
<input type="text" ID="JOB_CODETextBox" runat="server" 
 value='<%# Eval("JOB_CODE") %>' readonly="readonly" 
 onclick="$('#basic-modal-content').modal({
                                          appendTo:'form', persist: true,
                                          onClose: function (dialog) 
                                                   {
                                                      /*
           I want to assign here a value to the textbox control
           like this: JOB_CODETextBox = 'something...'
           I tried this: 
           $find('<%= JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>').value = 'something..'
           but it didn't work!! the find function returns [null]
                                                      */
                                                      $.modal.close();
                                                   }
                                         } );" />
```

Any help!!

Comment: Is the `telerik:GridTemplateColumn` part of another control? What does the rendered html look like?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('#'+'<%= JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>').val('something');
```

or (C# only):

```
$('<%= "#" + JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>').val('something');
```

or using JavaScript/ECMAScript:

```
document.getElementById('<%= JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>').value = 'something';
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but the binding (<%= JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID %>) doesn't work, it still give me the same value in javascript, it didn't replace it with the actual client id, any idea !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the telerik control you are using so I'm going to assume it's similar to other databound controls. Operating with that in mind, here is an example using a `Repeater` control.

here's the markup

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <input type="text" id="JOB_CODETextBox" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

in this situation, I usually generate the javascript server side.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder();

js.AppendLine("  <script>");

// we'll store all the control references in a list 
// since there will be one for each item in the repeater
js.AppendLine("    var JOB_CODETextBox_list = [];"); 

for (int j = 0; j < this.rpt1.Items.Count; j++)
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl JOB_CODETextBox;

    // try to locate the copy of the control local to each item
    JOB_CODETextBox = (HtmlGenericControl)this.rpt1.Items[j].FindControl("JOB_CODETextBox");

    if (JOB_CODETextBox != null) // make sure you found something
    {
        js.AppendFormat("JOB_CODETextBox_list.push(document.getElementById('{0}'));", JOB_CODETextBox.ClientID);
        js.AppendLine();
    }
}
js.AppendLine("  </script>");

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "JOB_CODE", js.ToString(), false);
```

that should generate a script that gets a reference to all instances of that input control within the Repeater. after it runs, you can access the items client side like

```
    JOB_CODETextBox_list[n].value = 'something';
```